# How to make Tortoise to recursively update even from disconnected repositories?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Tortoise, by default, updates recursively.
However, I need it to recursively update even when the directories down in the tree are not connected to the root directory.

Ex:

1. c:\A (file system) maps to http://rep/a (SVN)
2. c:\A\B (file system) maps to http://rep/a/b (SVN)
3. *c:\A\B\C (file system) maps to http://rep/c (SVN)*

See? If I update c:\A, by default, c:A\B\C won't be updated.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: You could consider using externals instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [svn hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks). More specifically you would need `Post-update` hook which has following parameters: `PATH DEPTH REVISION ERROR CWD`. You could decide whether to update `c` based on `ERROR` parameter, which should be empty if no error occurred. Additionally look at the [sample client hook scripts](http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/client-side/) from tortoise svn.